# Would webRTC be supported on any iOS browser?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, webrtc

Why is WebRTC not supported on Chrome for iOS? Is there any hard limitation for support?

Does anyone know of any plan to support WebRTC on any iOS browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball is [in Apple's court](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/bch_feIJn88) and it has to do with inherit limitations put down by Apple. Apple is very very quiet and particular about such things.

Also, WebRTC is not a finalized standard and I surely doubt that Apple will accept it until it is fully standardized. Heck, Microsoft still technically does not support it(meaning that IE itself does not support it yet).

You could always just make a [native application](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/) and subvert the browser.

There is also the Ericsson browser that may support WebRTC but [it has not looked promising on iOS either](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/ios/discuss-webrtc/Yhn8y_9CFP0/0m_Kn4NPAlEJ)